# How to configure what gets rendered on server-side in Rendr?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, server-side-rendering, rendr

Where to configure what part gets rendered on server-side and what renders on client-side while using Rendr.js?
The documentation and blogs everywhere mention that it's main purpose is to make a common way to write client and server code.

> Rendr is a small library that allows you to run your Backbone.js apps seamlessly on both the client and the server. Allow your web server to serve fully-formed HTML pages to any deep link of your app, while preserving the snappy feel of a traditional Backbone.js client-side MVC app.

But how to configure when server side rendering happens? Or does Rendr decide on it's own?

What I want to do is decide which part gets rendered on server side since I am trying to develop a single page application.

Comment: I don't know much about `rendr` but it seems it just helps you render stuff on backend using backbone.js code.
So it seems you render whatever you want to render from server side, and send the JavaScript for rendering other stuff in client side when user interaction happens.

Seems like a decision you make and design your code accordingly, not a configuration they can provide. Why do you think it should be/can be a configuration?

Comment: @TJ It doesn't look like it allows us to decide what to render from server side. Configuration I expect is this decision. Not exactly like a configuration file or anything but the freedom to decide what part gets rendered on server. From what I have grasped so far, it looks like when a new page is opened, it renders the first load from server and rest is handled on the client. And all of it is hidden and is implicitly handled.